# how to make an operator function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to make an operators to an object and I wonder what is the best way.

for example for the operator add

can I write this in this way?

```
def _add_(self,other):
   new=self.add(self,other)// can I write like that?
    return new
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types Take a look at that.

Comment: Why don't you move code from `add` to `__add__` and use `__add__` everywhere instead of `add`? It will save you one function call, and there will be less duplication.

Comment: `self.add(self,other)` seems to contain one `self` more than needed...

Comment: What type does `self.add` return?

Answer (score 6):

You would use the python magic function `__add__` to take care of the `+`:

Example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.num + other

a = A(6)

>>> print a+5
11
```

For greater flexibility, you should also define `__radd__`, this is for the reverse addition case `5+a` which would *not* work in the example above.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.num + other
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.num + other

>>> a = A(6)
>>> print 5+a
11
>>> print a+5
11
```

Or if you want to return as an object instead of an `int`, you can do it as:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def __add__(self, other):
        return A(self.num + other)

a = A(5)
b = a+5
print b.num
10
print a.num
5
```

What has been demonstrated above is [`operator overloading`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names). It overrides the built-in default methods for handling operators by letting the user define custom methods for the operators.

Here is a list you might find useful as to [**which operators can be overloaded**](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html#SpecialMethods)

Comment: might be an idea to explain to him what operator overloading is.

Comment: @user3603535, sorry meant "to her"!

Comment: yes, I see you added a link for operator overloading.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it returns an int.  If I did `b = a + 5`, should `b` be an `int` or an instance of class `A`?  I vote for the latter.

Comment: @cdarke, so you want it to be an instance of A instead of an int?

Comment: @sshashank124: yes, the example you linked with returns `self`, not an `int`as in your reply above.

Comment: @cdarke, You think I should include it in my answer?

Comment: there is also `__iadd__` (`self.num +=` is appropriate for it). Returning `int` instead of `A` type makes `a + 6 + 1` different from `a + 7` (due to side-effects) that is not intuitive.

Comment: It depends what the OP wants, but the example you linked to changes `self`.  If you did `b = a + 5` then generally you would not expect `a` to change!

Comment: @cdarke, Taken care of that as well. See my answer.

Comment: @cdarke, I must say. Thanks to your help and everyone else's, this is turning into one of my better answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, This is my new approach for your +6+1 statement. http://repl.it/SRy/1 Answer has also been updated.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: have you consider copying `self` (`copy.deepcopy`), doing the addition to the copy, then returning the copy?  That way, ` b = a + 5` does not change `a`.  It does return a new object though, so `a = a + 5` might cause issues (you can't overload operator = in Python).

Comment: @cdarke: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: actually you are doing it, that's fine.